# Is a bug in laravel 7.x?

Tags: php, laravel

I got a little gap in the security authority on laravel 7, whether this is known or not. I hope I get help.

My case study,
When I want to create a settings feature for my users I have to use the PUT / POST method, I choose POST because it's more simple and flexible for Ajax. But a little problem on the part

```
<form action = "localhost: 99 / settings / update / 1"
```

when I change 1 to 2, the data that changes is the data of another user. How to resolve this bug flexibly. I found a number of ways but in my opinion is less flexible. Thank you

Comment: By which terms is this a "bug"? Are you talking of any built-in feature of Laravel?

Comment: I think the bug is a problem in the application that results in something we don't expect. Btw thank you for reminding. Have a solution for this?

Comment: Based on your limited code and explanation, this does not appear to be a bug.  It's a problem with your implementation of Laravel.  You need to use [authorization and policies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization) to restrict who can update data.  A user should only be able to update their own data, but it's up to you to make these determinations.

Comment: I don't have any solution - can you share more information first? Where's the code to update any data? Where does that check whether the current user is allowed to edit tht data?

Comment: this is not a bug in the framework and not even your code, your expectations are just not inline with what is happening... the framework provides "authorization" functionality for this purpose though, if you choose to use it

Answer (score 1):

Please go through [Laravel Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies)

As you mentioned that **what if** a user inspect elements and changes the id from 1 to 2... well that is a use-case you have to cover from the back-end where the update (or crud operations) happens. And you can easily do that with Laravel Policies. The documentation is self explanatory.